# Want to use a lambda function to change the type of a cell if it is type float

Tags: python, pandas, types

I'd like to convert any cell that is type `float` to type `int`:

My thought was use lambda functions like this:

```
df["ev_id"].apply(lambda x: [int(x) if x is type(float)])
```

But this raises a syntax error which I'm not able to catch. Any help would be much appreciated.

Original data:

```
ev_id
" "
343.0
234.0
" "
212.0
"Temp"
```

Transformed:

```
ev_id
" "
343
234
" "
212
"Temp"
```

Comment: If still problem, can you add some data sample?

Comment: Using isinstance still raised an error. Please find sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lambda function you want:

```
lambda x: int(x) if isinstance(x, float) else x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.update.html) by `integer` values - first use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for replace non numeric to `NaN`s, then remove them by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html) and cast:

```
s = pd.to_numeric(df['ev_id'], errors='coerce').dropna().astype(int)
print (s)
1    343
2    234
4    212
Name: ev_id, dtype: int32

df['ev_id'].update(s)
print (df)
  ev_id
0      
1   343
2   234
3      
4   212
5  Temp
```